# XCFramework "Cannot load underlying module"

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, llvm

I've built an SDK as an XCFramework, which shares dependencies with the app that uses it. When I build, I'm getting:

`...SDK.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface:20:8: Cannot load underlying module for...`

This occurs in the Compile Swift Sources action and the break is in the `import MySharedDepedency` statement in the swiftinterface file

As stated, the SDK in the project as an xcframework bundle. MySharedDependency is fulfilled with cocoapods.  `use_modular_headers` is set in the `Podfile`, it's `modulemap` is included in the linker flags (by cocoapods).

Its DOES work if I use the `use_frameworks!` flag in the `Podfile` but only with dynamic linkage and for internal politics reasons, I need this to work with static linkage. If I add the `:linkage => :static` argument, I get the same error as with no `use_frameworks!` call

I've tried changing the order of the linked frameworks in Build Phases (so that the pods are linked before the SDK framework). I've tried adding recursive header/framework/module search paths everywhere I can find a MyDependency.modulemap...

Yes, I've cleaned caches, deintegrated, clean installed, erased deriveddata, restarted xcode, my machine, ...

Argh! Thanks for any help...

Comment: It seems that one or more of your dependencies does not support M1 architecture(and your SDK does), just get rid of that architecture in the xcbuild command

Comment: If your policies are that restricted, have you considered using it as a SPM package or even a submodule?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exactly the same scenario and the same problem

I solved using `@_implementationOnly` in every file from my xcframework's code like:

```
@_implementationOnly import Alamofire
```

After that just rebuild your XCFramework, clean and build your app's project.

It works like a charm without `use_framework`s!

Comment: Woh. never heard of that!  Where did you get it from??

Comment: A similar question with a similar answer but a little more information.
https://forums.swift.org/t/challenges-creating-an-xcframework-for-native-libraries/41600